# Why is my binary K-dimensional tree not rendered properly?

Tags: python, anytree

I'm working with anytree package in Python for creating and displaying a K-dimension tree, however the tree is not rendered properly.

This is part of my source code for my K-dimensional node:

```
import numpy as np
from anytree import NodeMixin


class KdData:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.key = None


class KdNode(KdData, NodeMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, children=None, axis: int = 0) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.axis = axis
        self.parent = parent
        if children:
            self.children = children

    def set_key(self, key):
        self.key = np.array(key)
        if self.key is not None:
            self.children = [
                KdNode(axis=(self.axis + 1) % self.key.shape[0]),
                KdNode(axis=(self.axis + 1) % self.key.shape[0])
            ]

    def get_left_node(self):
        if self.key is None:
            return None
        return self.children[0]

    def get_right_node(self):
        if self.key is None:
            return None
        return self.children[1]

    def insert(self, key):
        if self.key is None:
            self.set_key(key)
        elif key[self.axis] < self.key[self.axis]:
            self.get_left_node().insert(key)
        else:
            self.get_right_node().insert(key)

    # Other functions are omitted because it's not relavant to the question
```

Then this is the tree I created.

```
tree = KdNode()
tree.set_key(np.array([5,6]))
tree.insert([4,7])
tree.insert([17,16])
tree.insert([7,8])
tree.insert([1,4])
tree.insert([9,13])
```

And this is my exporter:

```
def node_attribute(node):
    att = ""
    att += "shape=plaintext"
    return att

def edge_att(source, target):
    att = ""
    if target.key is None:
        att += "style=invis"
    return att

from anytree.exporter.dotexporter import DotExporter, UniqueDotExporter

dot_obj = UniqueDotExporter(tree,
    nodenamefunc=lambda node: node.key if node.key is not None else "",
    nodeattrfunc=lambda node: node_attribute(node),
    edgeattrfunc=lambda src, tgt: edge_att(src, tgt))
```

My obtained result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRvDZ.png). The expected result is that [4 7] node and [17 16] node are in the same rank.

Why was my K-dimensional tree not rendered properly?

Comment: if you remove `"style=invis"` then it all nodes have arrow to the same place at the bottom - it is `None`. And maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `att += "style=invis"` and you use `None` instead of `""` in
`nodenamefunc=lambda node: node.key if node.key is not None else None,`
then you get:

[image]

And if you add `__repr__` in `KdNode`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.key)
```

and you run `print(RenderTree(tree))` then you see:

```
[5 6]
├── [4 7]
│   ├── [1 4]
│   │   ├── None
│   │   └── None
│   └── None
└── [17 16]
    ├── [7 8]
    │   ├── None
    │   └── [ 9 13]
    │       ├── None
    │       └── None
    └── None
```

And probably this `None` makes all problem.

---

If you use `filter=lambda node: node.key is not None`

```
dot_obj = UniqueDotExporter(tree,
    nodenamefunc=lambda node: node.key if node.key is not None else "",
    nodeattrfunc=lambda node: node_attribute(node),
    edgeattrfunc=lambda src, tgt: edge_att(src, tgt),
    filter_=lambda node: node.key is not None,
    )
```

then you get:

[image]

So maybe you should remove `None` from your tree. But I don't know how to do it.

---

Full code which I used for tests - so everyone can simply copy and test it.

```
import numpy as np
from anytree import NodeMixin, AnyNode, RenderTree
from anytree.exporter.dotexporter import UniqueDotExporter
from anytree.dotexport import RenderTreeGraph

class KdData:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.key = None


class KdNode(KdData, NodeMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, children=None, axis: int = 0) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.axis = axis
        self.parent = parent
        if children:
            self.children = children

    def set_key(self, key):
        self.key = np.array(key)
        if self.key is not None:
            self.children = [
                KdNode(axis=(self.axis + 1) % self.key.shape[0]),
                KdNode(axis=(self.axis + 1) % self.key.shape[0])
            ]

    def get_left_node(self):
        if self.key is None:
            return None
        return self.children[0]

    def get_right_node(self):
        if (self.key is None):
            return None
        return self.children[1]

    def insert(self, key):
        if self.key is None:
            self.set_key(key)
        elif key[self.axis] < self.key[self.axis]:
            self.get_left_node().insert(key)
        else:
            self.get_right_node().insert(key)

    # Other functions are omitted because it's not relavant to the question
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.key)
    
# --- main ---
        
tree = KdNode()
tree.set_key(np.array([5,6]))
tree.insert([4,7])
tree.insert([17,16])
tree.insert([7,8])
tree.insert([1,4])
tree.insert([9,13])

def node_attribute(node):
    att = ""
    att += "shape=plaintext"
    return att

def edge_att(source, target):
    att = ""
    if target.key is None:
        att += "style=invis"
        #pass
    return att

dot_obj = UniqueDotExporter(tree,
    #nodenamefunc=lambda node: node.key if node.key is not None else None,
    nodenamefunc=lambda node: node.key if node.key is not None else "",
    nodeattrfunc=lambda node: node_attribute(node),
    edgeattrfunc=lambda src, tgt: edge_att(src, tgt),
    filter_=lambda node: node.key is not None,
    )
    
dot_obj.to_picture('image.png')

print(RenderTree(tree))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. After I remove nodenamefunc, it works. I first thought that the node only display `name` of the node. But in fact, what I should set is `label` instead and let the anytree handle the node name itself.